# Unknown Url Impression

Tags: heroku, google-analytics

I have a dev site running on Heroku.  I put in google analytics.  It was working fine.  I decided to create a new tracking code so I could wipe out any previous data and start fresh.

I put in the new tracking code in my code, then pushed to Heroku.  I noticed I was getting hits.  But it was some weird url, looks like spam but what is this /www1.free-share-buttons.top ?  why in the world is that getting logged?

[image]

Comment: Def spam, but you should repost this to webmasters as it's not code related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely to be the result of so-called referral spam. You are getting hits from bots, which are targeting random UA identifiers, and not from actual visits and Analytics code on your website. To double-check this, you can view your Top pages reports in Analytics, by adding Hostname as secondary dimensions. You'll see (not set) next to these unknown pages, which means, they were pushed into Analytics from devices other than your site. There are several methods to prevent this happening, e.g. by adding an Analytics View filter, that prevents other Hostnames to appear in your reports.